# How to set image url of the image inside gridview based on certain attribute value of the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a image control inside gridview along with other attributes. I want to know how can I set the image url property or How can I assign certain static Images based on attribute value say customer name? I want to do this since I am not storing images in my database.Please guide me how can I do this? Do I need to use `RowDataBound` property of the gridview?

I wanted to try something like this-

```
dt = g1.return_dt("select cust_name from tbl_details");
if(dt.Rows.Equals("XYZ"))
{
Set Image Url
}
else if(dt.Rows.Equals("XXX"))
{
Set Image Url
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table: "tblA"

```
id     int    identity
name   nvarcher(50)
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView><br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblA]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //fill gridview
        if( ! IsPostBack )
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        string name = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;            
        Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");
        if (img==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(name == "XYZ")
        {
            img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/a.jpg";
        }
        else if(name == "XPS")
        {
              img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/b.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            //default static image
            img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/c.jpg";
        }
}
```

Comment: I know how to set Image Url. I want to understand if I am using say 3 images and I want to provide certain condition such that for every gridview row based on that condition the image will change. And within If/Else statement I will provide static Image url.Please guide me in that respect.

Comment: Thanks a lot Samiey. This answer was very helpful :-)
Happy New Year Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server"   
              AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="DangerDownstream"
              onpageindexchanging="GridView3_PageIndexChanging" 
              backcolor="White" onrowdatabound="GridView3_RowDataBound"
              PageSize="5" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              EnableModelValidation="True">
        <RowStyle CssClass="station_grid" />              
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="DangerDownstream" />
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notification">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Image ID="Img" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="25px"/>
                  <asp:Label ID="Ln" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CS**

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("Img"); 
img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/warning2.png";
```

Comment: Hello Amarnath,
I want to use certain condition such that, for every gridview row the image will change based on that condition. That is what I mentioned in my question. Please tell me can I do it by using GridviewDataBound property?